# Only some selected programs being able to access the internet, How to fix it?

Tags: 13.04

I'm running Ubuntu 13.04 currently and am seeing that only Skype is able to access the internet. No other program is able to access the internet.

Everything was fine until yesterday. What could I be doing wrong, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this may be DNS problem. you can set /etc/resolv.conf with content

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Then try surf website again.